Wildfly 31 x Hibernate Envers : EnversService#initialize should be called only once
Hello im trying to run Hibernate envers on my wildfly server, project can be built with mvn clean install and tests for it runs fine but when i want to deploy it to the server i receive error, i also find out that error occurs as soon as i add solo dependency to pom.xml for hibernate envers currently on version 6.5.2.Final:
09:34:51,107 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 84) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.persistenceunit."lap-internal-ear-0.4.0-SNAPSHOT.ear/ibbw.lap-uebergreifende-lap-uebergreifende-parent-0.4.0-SNAPSHOT.jar#LapDBEntityManager2": org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.persistenceunit."lap-internal-ear-0.4.0-SNAPSHOT.ear/ibbw.lap-uebergreifende-lap-uebergreifende-parent-0.4.0-SNAPSHOT.jar#LapDBEntityManager2": java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: EnversService#initialize should be called only once
    at org.jboss.as.jpa@31.0.0.Final//org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:187)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa@31.0.0.Final//org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:117)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
    at org.wildfly.security.elytron-base@2.2.3.Final//org.wildfly.security.manager.WildFlySecurityManager.doChecked(WildFlySecurityManager.java:664)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa@31.0.0.Final//org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:202)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1990)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1377)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:840)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:513)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: EnversService#initialize should be called only once
    at org.hibernate@6.4.2.Final//org.hibernate.envers.boot.internal.EnversServiceImpl.initialize(EnversServiceImpl.java:92)
    at org.hibernate@6.4.2.Final//org.hibernate.envers.boot.internal.AdditionalJaxbMappingProducerImpl.produceAdditionalMappings(AdditionalJaxbMappingProducerImpl.java:92)
    at org.hibernate@6.4.2.Final//org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.processAdditionalJaxbMappingProducer(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:548)
    at org.hibernate@6.4.2.Final//org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:340)
    at org.hibernate@6.4.2.Final//org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1432)
    at org.hibernate@6.4.2.Final//org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1503)
    at org.hibernate.jipijapa-hibernate6@31.0.0.Final//org.jboss.as.jpa.hibernate.TwoPhaseBootstrapImpl.build(TwoPhaseBootstrapImpl.java:32)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa@31.0.0.Final//org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:159)
    ... 10 more

persistance.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/persistence https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_3_1.xsd"
             version="3.1">

    <persistence-unit name="LapDBEntityManager2" transaction-type="JTA">
        <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>

        <jta-data-source>java:/PostgresLapDS</jta-data-source>

        <class>entity.person.PersonEntity</class>
      

        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="org.postgresql.Driver"/>
            <property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache" value="true"/>
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false"/>
            <property name="hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans" value="true"/>

            <property name="hibernate.envers.autoRegisterListeners" value="true"/>
            <property name="hibernate.envers.audit_table_prefix" value=""/>
            <property name="hibernate.envers.audit_table_suffix" value="_aud"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>

Classes for envers:
@Entity
@Table(name = "rev_info")
@RevisionEntity(LapRevisionListener.class)
public class AuditEnversInfo extends DefaultRevisionEntity {
    @Column(name = "modifier_user")
    private String modifierUser;

    public String getModifierUser() {
        return modifierUser;
    }

    public void setModifierUser(String modifierUser) {
        this.modifierUser = modifierUser;
    }
}
public class LapRevisionListener implements RevisionListener {
    @Override
    public void newRevision(Object revisionEntity) {
        AuditEnversInfo auditEnversInfo = (AuditEnversInfo) revisionEntity;
        auditEnversInfo.setModifierUser(getUsername());
    }

    //TODO: get there name of person that is logged in
    private String getUsername() {
        return "modifierUser1";
    }
}


Do you have envers as part of your deployment ?

@ehsavoie I have it just as part of my pom.xml, then im building ear and deploying it to the wildfly

In what scope ? Is it part of the ear ?
